# mapping file-* to a property

Tags: ant

I'd like to:

```
<unjar src="lib/mst-service-impl*.zip"
```

but I can't put an asterisk in there.  It is only one file, but I don't want to hardcode the version in there.  Is there a way to create a property with the asterisk (I know this particular example doesn't work, but perhaps something along these lines):

```
<property name="my.jar" file="lib/mst-service-impl*.zip">
```

so that I could then do this:

```
<unjar src="${my.jar}"
```

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - I'm dumb.  I totally missed this:

```
<unzip dest="${build.test.classes}">
 <fileset dir="${build.lib}">
  <include name="**/mst-service-impl-*.jar"/>
 </fileset>
</unzip>
```